# using CSS content & :after to show a <span> inside an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on an image gallery inside a web template, similar to this [link](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html). now currently when i click on an image it will be shown inside a jquery slider. but i need the image inside the slider to show the `span` defined inside the markup `<span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>villa2</em></span>`, where each image will have the following markup  :-

```
   <li>
        <figure><a href="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_bigimg1.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_img1.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>villa2</em></span></a></figure>
    </li>
```

so i define the following inside my css file:-

```
#gallerySlider .placeholder:after {
  content: "test";
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  z-Index: 1;
  bottom: 42px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: -8px;
}
```

which will show the following :-

[image]

where i was able to add the text "test " inside the slider. but can anyone adivce how i can do these 2 modifications:-

1) instead of showing a static text inside the slider using the following css:-

```
  #gallerySlider .placeholder:after {
      content: "test";
```

how i can force the CSS content , to show the `<span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>villa2</em></span>` which is related to the rendered image ?

2) how i can move the content to be below the image instead of being on the left ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

now after many tests and modifications i did the following modification to the loadImage callback function inside the Touchtouch script :-

```
function loadImage(src, callback){
            var img = $('<img>').on('load', function(){
                callback.call(img);
            });

            img.attr('src', src);



                // get all the captions (should probably be done with variable referring to something about above selector)
                var allcaptions = $("figure span");

                // setTimeout is a hack here, since the ".placeholders" don't exist yet
                //setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".placeholder").each(function (i) {

                        // in each .placeholder, copy its caption's mark-up into it (remove the img first)
                        var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();
                       // caption.find("img").remove();
                        $(this).append("<div class='caption'>" + caption.html() + "</div>");
                    });
       // }, 500
        //);
}
```

this seems to show the span as follow:-

[image]

but i am facing two problems:-

**First Problem** as shown on the above picture the text will be shown twice , specifically when i click on the next and previous arrows, here is the built-in code for the next & prevoise arrows :-

```
function showNext(){

        // If this is not the last image
        if(index+1 < items.length){
            index++;
            offsetSlider(index);
            preload(index+1);
        }
        else{
            // Trigger the spring animation

            slider.addClass('rightSpring');
            setTimeout(function(){
                slider.removeClass('rightSpring');
            },500);
        }
    }

    function showPrevious(){

        // If this is not the first image
        if(index>0){
            index--;
            offsetSlider(index);
            preload(index-1);
        }
        else{
            // Trigger the spring animation

            slider.addClass('leftSpring');
            setTimeout(function(){
                slider.removeClass('leftSpring');
            },500);
        }
    }
```

**Second problem.** is that as i click on next & previous arrows the image will keep loosing its position and after many next & previous i will end up having the image on the following position at the bottom of the page:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce how i can fix these 2 issues ?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudoelements :after and :before make possible to add an element into the html flow with just css... but that's it. An element which can be text, shapes, images (using css instructions as `content:url('image.png')`, etc. But you can't add  html in the `content:`of the pseudoelement (as logn as I know).

You could use simple jquery as:

```
$(".placeholder").after("<span class="your-class-to-style"><strong>Project name:</strong><em>villa2</em></span>");
```

But if you have control of the html I would just include the span there.

(note: `:after` and`:before` follow the html flow so to reposition them you need to use `position:absolute` not forgetting to add `relative` to the parent)

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful reply, i will try your approach. yes i have a full control over the html,, but i want things to be dynamic,, so i construct the image as shown in my markup and force the script to read the markup dynamically. because the same <span> is being used to shown a box when you hover over the image on a web page , as shown in the link i provide ..

Comment: so is there a way to modify the  "jquery $(".placeholder").after(...)" to reference the "SPAN" inside the markup :- "<li> <figure><a href="livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/…; class="thumb"><img src="livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/img/page3_img1.jpg"; alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>villa2</em></span></a></figure> </li>"

Comment: This will not work, since the plugin is doing `placeholders.eq(index).html(this);` when the image is loaded

Comment: @TomSarduy so you mean i will not be able to insert any thing after the image is loaded,, but i was able to show a static text... i thought i will be able to show the span instead.. so what do u recommend me to do ? to look for another plugin ?

Comment: @Alvaro Menéndez can you please check my edit section on my original question. where i tried modifying the built-in touch script but i am facing some issues..

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm a designer and my knowledge is specially html and css. I can add some jquery scripts here and there but can't help with your code, specially If I can't check it out "live". If you have any url where I can take a look, I will, but not many chances I would be able to help you :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you check the sources, you will see they are using the [TouchTouch](https://github.com/martinaglv/touchTouch/) jQuery plugin (a little bit outdated by the way). Since the plugin doesn't have options or callbacks, you will have to do this manually. The key is in the following line:

```
loadImage(items.eq(index).attr('href'), function(){
    placeholders.eq(index).html(this);
});
```

So, even if you add the texts with jQuery, the plugin will remove it from the placeholder and add only the image.

Comment: yes i know that it uses TouchTouch script but i did not knwo that it is outdated. so my first question if you can help do u suggest to use another plugin ? and do u recommend specific ones ? second question u mentioned " Since the plugin doesn't have options or callbacks, you will have to do this manually. " so can you adivce how to achieve this manually ?

Comment: also i checked the touchtouch script source code and i see that it have a call back function as follow :- 
  
     function loadImage(src, callback){
         var img = $('<img>').on('load', function(){
             callback.call(img);
         });
   
         img.attr('src', src); .. as you mentioned it does not have a call back function ..

Comment: can you please check my edit section on my original question. where i tried modifying the built-in touch script but i am facing some issues..